# Sexy drop down menu hide on click outside

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I think many of you know the [sexy drop down menu](http://www.google.com/?hl=en#hl=en&gs_rn=9&gs_ri=psy-ab&qe=c2V4eSBkcm8&qesig=YpYi9EK2Zn-pGuFMDpIzHA&pkc=AFgZ2tkSywKF5Ep0oVdlWAAR809JDTirIvODthLK9O7rdyxJcJVq95dxG3QgdtSMhq3CbNz9cd-jxrWF32L-upgJvVviEeW7Rg&pq=hide%20drop%20down%20menu%20on%20click%20out&cp=8&gs_id=4r&xhr=t&q=sexy+drop+down+menu&es_nrs=true&pf=p&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&oq=sexy+dro&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=5ed0226ea41938e3&biw=1920&bih=1088) that uses jQuery and CSS to style the drop down menu.

When you click on a arrow trigger, it shows the drop down menu, when you hover out it hides it.

My problem is that I can't get it to hide the drop down menu on click outside. I've searched on Internet, but unfortunately didn't find anything.

My code is :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('li:has(ul)').addClass('has-children');

    // Sexy Drop Down Menu
    $('li.has-children').append('<span class="dropdown"></span>'); // Adding a span tag with .dropdown class to <li> with child elements

    $("li.has-children .dropdown").click(function(){ // When trigger is clicked...

        // Following events are applied to the subnav itself (moving subnav up and down)
        $(this).parent().find("ul.sub-menu").slideDown('fast').show(); // Drop down the subnav on click

        $(this).parent().hover(function(){
        }, function(){
            $(this).parent().find("ul.sub-menu").slideUp('slow'); // When the mouse hovers out of the subnav, move it back up
        });
    });
});
```

I tried to replace `$(this).parent().hover(function(){` by `$(this).parent().click(function(){` but it didn't work.

Can someone help me with this problem, please?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In a way your question doesn't make sense because when you want to click outside you already hovered outside.
Usually you want to do something like `$(document).click(function(){/*hide your menu*/});`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$(this).parent().hover(function(){
```

With

```
$('html').click(function(){
```

It should then close when you click somewhere else on the page (I assume that is what you meant by click outside).

I have used this on a few sites to close a menu. It is hard to guarantee it will work on all sites without testing, as I expected to run into z-index issues, but it worked first time for me on mine.

**Update:**

Replace

```
    $(this).parent().hover(function(){
    }, function(){
        $(this).parent().find("ul.sub-menu").slideUp('slow'); // When the mouse hovers out of the subnav, move it back up
    });
```

With

```
    $('html').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find("ul.sub-menu").slideUp('slow'); // When the mouse hovers out of the subnav, move it back up
    });
```

Comment: You probably will also need a stop propagation event for when you click inside the `menu`. [Example is given here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element/153047#153047)

Comment: It doesn't work, unfortunately. It shows the menu and immediately hides it.

Comment: I have updated the answer. The original code's hover() took 2 functions, whereas we would only need one now.

Also Pankrates is correct that you may need that stop propagation example as well.

Answer (score 0):

Capitalizing on Ben's answer, If clicking on the menu hides it immediately, why not reverse the click and hover functions:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('li:has(ul)').addClass('has-children');

    // Sexy Drop Down Menu
    $('li.has-children').append('<span class="dropdown"></span>'); // Adding a span tag with .dropdown class to <li> with child elements

    $("li.has-children .dropdown").hover(function(){ // Change click to hover event...

        // Following events are applied to the subnav itself (moving subnav up and down)
        $(this).parent().find("ul.sub-menu").slideDown('fast').show(); // Drop down the subnav on hover

        $('html').click(function(){
        }, function(){
            $(this).parent().find("ul.sub-menu").slideUp('slow'); // When the mouse clicks out of the subnav, move it back up
        });
    });
});
```

This way hovering over the arrow will drill down and clicking anywhere else will hide it...if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I'd upvote Ben's answer if I had enough rep since this works just fine, I just swapped out the click on the arrow to become a hover drill down instead